# Were Gale and Pryce meant to be similar characters?

Tags: breaking-bad, better-call-saul

Both Gale and Pryce were people involved in the legitimate world of "chemistry" who both without any pressure became involved in criminal activities. They had, I think, similar personalities although Gale was much brighter and savvier.

They both got burnt, one more severely than the other. I wonder why have two such characters?

Comment: Pryce is the Pryce yo

Answer (score 4):

### Gale and Pryce are from two different shows.

First, it's worth noting that while they exist in the same TV universe, they are not from the same shows and their appearances took place years apart from one another. Yes, Gale does make a short cameo on *Better Call Saul*, but you're really talking about two characters from different shows. It might be worth asking why have two very similar characters on the same show, but Gale is a *Breaking Bad* character who cameos once on *Better Call Saul*, and Pryce is a *Better Call Saul* character who never appears or is mentioned on *Breaking Bad*.

### You are overstating their similarities.

**Professional:** Gale is a skilled PhD-candidate chemist. Pryce is an IT professional at a pharmaceuticals company (i.e., really just a computer guy at a company that happens to have a connection to chemistry). Both professions lend an opportunity to commit crime... but really so do most jobs.

**Criminal:** Gale is invited into a life of crime by a powerful benefactor (Gus) who recognizes his genius, and he is prevented from engaging in crime at first because Gus is saving him for the lab when it is complete. By contrast, we don't know how Pryce got mixed up in crime, but most likely he was approached by Nacho for the deals we saw. He has no remarkable skills, just remarkable access to the drugs his company makes. He likely started out doing it on his own and Nacho caught wind that there was a guy who could get pills. Gale is a skilled and protected employee of a criminal enterprise; Pryce is a free-lancer engaged by a member of a criminal enterprise as a side gig without the enterprise's knowledge, and who later victimizes him.

**Profile:** While Gale seems a little over-eager at times, he is able to maintain a low profile despite his criminal prominence. He is working as the chief chemist of the top drug lord in the American Southwest, but he lives in a modest apartment, drives a modest car, and effectively keeps a low profile (apart from foolishly keeping a notebook of his illegal activities). Pryce by contrast wants to be a "Playah" as the license plate on his huge, flashy Hummer says. He draws attention to himself, seeks contact with the police, and nearly gets himself caught.

**Appearances:** Gale is a dork and he really doesn't care what anyone thinks about that. He is pretty comfortable in his own skin, singing his silly songs and telling his silly jokes to anyone. Pryce by contrast is a dork trying to pretend to be something else. He sees himself as a pretty tough customer... or at least he wants to.

**Personality:** At the surface level, both of these guys are "dorky," but they are distinctly different brands of dorkiness. Gale is an educated, cultured guy. He is an advanced academic and is familiar with great literature and gourmet cooking. His dorkiness derives from an affinity for strange things (like making videos of himself singing Bowie songs). Pryce by contrast probably has a B.A. in computer science at best. He doesn't seem that interested in culture or have any noteworthy hobbies. Even his obsession for his baseball cards seems mainly based on the fact that they were his father's.

**Listening:** When people talk to Gale, he listens. Gus gives him direction and he follows it. Walt has a better way to make meth and he is willing to learn. Pryce by contrast has a listening problem, he is too self-absorbed. Mike tells him not to go to a meet in the Hummer - he doesn't listen. Mike tells him not to go without backup - he doesn't listen. Mike practically has to smack him in the face to keep him from talking to the cops.

**Story purposes:** The roles Gale and Pryce play in the story-telling is rather different. Gale is in the story to create tension between Gus and Walt--as long as Gale is there, Gus has the potential to rid himself of the need to keep Walt and Jesse around. Gale's death means Gus needs Walt... at least if he wants to sell the best meth. Pryce by contrast is primarily in the story to introduce Mike to Nacho and to allow Mike to show Nacho his important qualities. Pryce also later serves as a plausible source for Nacho to get empty drug capsules for his plan to get rid of Hector Salamanca.

### So no, they probably were not meant to be similar characters.

**I don't think these guys were meant to be really all that similar. They serve different purposes in the story lines and they are markedly different in a lot of ways once you look past their surface social awkwardness.**

Comment: You got a lot of real nice words here buddy, but we could replace them all with just these seven: Gale would never do a squat cobbler.

Comment: Also as per the Better Call Saul Insider podcast, Mark Proksch auditioned for the role of Craig Kettleman, and writer Thomas Schnauz liked him so much he kept him in mind when writing Pryce.

Comment: If Gale met Pryce he'd probably say "I don't think we're alike at all mr pryce, you are not a careful man"